# Extra '\' character in string python

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am trying to get user input as parameter on my function. I did this :

on **Utilities.py**

```
def EnterVersion()
    gVer = ""
    tgVer = ""
    while True:
          gVer = input(" Enter game version : ")
          if gVer ='':
             tgVer = tgVer[:-1]
             break
          else:
            gVer = '\'' + gVer + '\'' + ','
            tgVer += gVer

    tgVer = "\"(%s)\""%tgVer
    print(tgVer)
    return tgVer
```

on **a.py**

```
game_version = ""

def getGameVersion()
    game_version = utilities.EnterVersion()
    return game_version
```

When user input like this :

> Enter game version : 1
>   Enter game version : 2

EDIT :
I am using VS for Python
The output from the script (on the command line) is good :

> "('1','2')"

But, when I put watch on the variable, it went this way :
[image]

The output will be like this:

> "(\'1\',\'2\')"

Without extra '\' on it.

So, given that input my query (I am using pandas) doesn't ran.

Because it read the game version as :

> '\1'\ and '\2\'  , or
>   \'1\' and \'2\'

I am aware that '\' used to write special character in python.
But why I got it on mine?
Anyone can explain to me why I got extra '\' on my string?

Comment: does your code compile? (it didnt for me). 
This line seems wrong `gVer = '\'' + gVer + '\'' + ','
`

Comment: Hmm, 
Yes, I can compile it.
I am using version 3.3.2

Comment: @smushi replace `input()` with `raw_input()`

Comment: Solved!  
I was stupid enough to not aware about my mistake : Ah, I found it!!!.. on the EnterVersion() I put extra " " " so it error..it's not because '\'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have cupple of syntax error when i try to run it. and also it your expected output without changeing the code.

```
def EnterVersion():
    gVer = ""
    tgVer = ""
    while True:
          gVer = input(" Enter game version : ")
          if gVer =='':
             tgVer = tgVer[:-1]
             break
          else:
            gVer = '\'' + gVer + '\'' + ','
            tgVer += gVer

    tgVer = "\"(%s)\""%tgVer
    print(tgVer)
    return tgVer


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game_version = EnterVersion()
    print(game_version)
```

Comment: What was the output from it?

Comment: "('5','5')" this is output from python3.3

Answer (score 0):

Running code below with python2.7 will be ok:

```
def EnterVersion():
    gVer = ""
    tgVer = ""
    while True:
          gVer = raw_input(" Enter game version : ") #use raw_input here
          if gVer == '':
             tgVer = tgVer[:-1]
             break
          else:
            gVer = '\'' + gVer + '\'' + ','
            tgVer += gVer

    tgVer = "\"(%s)\""%tgVer
    print(tgVer)
    return tgVer
```

result：

```
 Enter game version : 2
 Enter game version : 4
 Enter game version : 1
 Enter game version : 2
 Enter game version : 
"('2','4','1','2')"
```

**EDIT**: What you have done is all right! But you should not see the resule in debug mode,because it use the string that will be represented in the code which is not the real output. i.e. if you see `"abc"` in the debug mode,and the real output string is `abc`, if you see "\'hi\'" in debug mode,the real out string will be 'hi',it is ok!

Comment: I am using version 3.3.2.
Ah yes, sorry. I got you all in wrong direction. Gonna update

Comment: @noobsee  see my EDIT,your code is ok but you are confused with represented string and real output string.

Comment: Ah, I found it!!!.. on the EnterVersion() I put extra " " " so it error..it's not because '\'